# Reclaim space in SQL Server 2005 database when dropping tables permanently

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm dropping out massive numbers of tables out of a SQL Server 2005 database. How do I shrink the database - assuming I'm not replacing the data or the tables? I'm archiving stuff to another db.

Comment: Do you need to shrink the database? is it critical? See these recent answers please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940533/does-sqls-delete-statement-truly-delete-data/1940569#1940569 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149605/freeing-up-space-in-sql-server/6150193#6150193

Comment: Yes. The tables are no longer used and the space is no longer required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DBCC Shrinkdatabase(0) --  Currently selected database
```

or

```
DBCC Shrinkdatabase(<databasename>) --  Named database
```

However, shrinking files will likely fragment your tables, particularly larger onces, as contents of tables get moved about within the file, so once shrunk it's a good idea to defragment your tables. This, of course, will make your files grow again, but probably not so large as they were before you dropped your old tables. (Err, that assumes that the dropped tables contained large quantities of data...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` command, or you can right-click the database, Tasks, Shrink, Database.