# free space after truncate table

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reclaim space in SQL Server 2005 database when dropping tables permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158324/reclaim-space-in-sql-server-2005-database-when-dropping-tables-permanently)

I had a table which took 20GB and it is not needed, but using DELETE statement was not an option since it would cause the LDF file to grow rapidly due to the logging of each row entry deleted.

So I've used TRUNCATE TABLE, though now the db still takes the same amount of space although I've deleted this table. I've read somewhere that I should use shrink database option, but the problem is they say it should delete all indexes in the database?

What would you recommend doing? Is there other way to free this unallocated space from the MDF file?

Thanks

Comment: Basically the same question as [SQL Server database size didn't decrease after deleting large number of rows.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28360/3690)

Comment: I don't know where you read/heard that a shrink would delete indexes -  but you shouldn't trust that source.

Comment: Question is: is this really worth it? Yes - you can shrink the database file. **BUT BE AWARE:** this will "upset" all your tables to the point that you'll suffer performance loss. If you shrink your database - all your indexes will be compromised and will suffer massive fragmentation. If you do insist on shrinking your database file to reclaim the space - you should also rebuild **all your indexes** after you do!

Comment: so is there any way to reclaim that 20gb size without compromising the indexes and defrag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shrinkfile instead

Syntax from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx)

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE 
(
    { file_name | file_id } 
    { [ , EMPTYFILE ] 
    | [ [ , target_size ] [ , { NOTRUNCATE | TRUNCATEONLY } ] ]
    }
)
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

> Shrinks the size of the specified data or log file for the current
>   database, or empties a file by moving the data from the specified file
>   to other files in the same filegroup, allowing the file to be removed
>   from the database. You can shrink a file to a size that is less than
>   the size specified when it was created. This resets the minimum file
>   size to the new value.

**Example**

```sql
/* change into your database */
USE dbName
/* determine the logical file name */
EXEC sp_helpfile
GO
/* shrink the file */
DBCC SHRINKFILE (logicalLogFileName)
GO
```

Comment: will this not cause indexes to be deleted and tables to be fragmented? does it really solve the issue with shrink?

Comment: What's the output of sp_helpfile?

Comment: name fileid filename filegroup size maxsize growth usage

MY_DB 1 D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\MY_DB.mdf PRIMARY 26627904 KB Unlimited 1024 KB data only
MY_DB_log 2 D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\MY_DB_log.ldf NULL 57664 KB 2147483648 KB 10% log only

Comment: sorry for format, just copy paste it into notepad and add line breaks (can't format)

Comment: ok your logfile actually is quite small 57MB while your datafile is currently consuming about 25 GB. Shrinking the datafile will not delete indexes but you might want to reorganize your index due to fragmentation after the huge deletion. run sp_updatestats to update your system statistics afterwards

Comment: This is a good document adressing index rebuilding / reorganization http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx

Comment: so, you'd recommend using SHRINKFILE on the MDF file and then reorganizing the indexes using sp_updatestats?